# Nested ng-repeat with same key have different values

Tags: angularjs

Hi am stuck somewhere in my code below image shows my response data I receive from Api.

[image]

this is my code I want to make a nested ng-repeat for my Genre but am getting error of

```
<div class="col-3" id="umovies" ng-repeat="movies in sectionInTheaterMovieProduct" lightgallery>
                <figure class="box movie-bx">
                    <div class="prod-img">
                        <a href="{{movies.HypCat_Name}}">
                            <img ng-src="{{movies.Image}}" alt="{{movies.cat_name}}"/>
                        </a>    
                    </div>      
                    <figcaption>
                        <div class=""><a href="{{movies.HypCat_Name}}">{{movies.cat_name}}</a></div>
                        <p class="notify">{{movies.Parent2Name}}</p>
                        <p class="notify movie-ty"><span ng-repeat="(key,value) in movies.Genre">{{Key}} : {{value}}</span></p>
                        <div class="review-rating">
                            <div class="avg-star">{{movies.Rating}}&nbsp;<span class="icon-rating unrated-star"></span></div>
                            <div class="recommendation">
                                <span class="icon-like"></span><span>{{movies.Recommendation}}%</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="reviews-cnt">
                                <a class="small" href="{{movies.HypCat_Name}}">{{movies.ReviewCount}}&nbsp;{{movies.ReviewCount == 1 ? 'Review' : 'Reviews'}}</a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>   
            </div>
```

[image]

can anyone help me please I need output shown in below image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use track by index to avoid duplicates error, since movies.Genre is a comma separated string

```
<span ng-repeat="(key,value) in movies.Genre.split(',') track by $index"
```

since movies.Genre is a comma separated string, you can use .split(',') to make it array.

Comment: Where to use track by $index I have two ng-repeat. I have used it for inner ng-repeat the error disappears but desired output is not achieved. it repeats for each character instead of genre word.

Comment: it should be on the inner ng-repeat, well post your json

Comment: <p class="notify movie-ty"><span ng-repeat="genre in movies.Genre track by $index">{{genre}}</span></p>. I have used this but it repeats each character instead of word.

Comment: can you post the json

Comment: check first image of question that is my response

Comment: ok the issue is your movies.genre is not a array, its a string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141501/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-uiupdates).

Comment: Please check for discussion in the above comment for answer